# Spring controller not getting JSON POST data from JS file

Tags: json, spring-mvc

From my JS file I am posting this JSON data.

```
myPayload[0].id=1&myPayload[0].name=Me&myPayload[0].pId=2&myPayload[0].pName=Dad
```

YUI Code:

```
var formElements = YAHOO.util.Connect.setForm("myFormId");
alert("New form elements:" + formElements); // Alerting POST data as shown above

YAHOO.util.Connect.resetFormState();

YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest("POST", "/mycontroller/save", {
    cache : false,
    success : function(res) {
        alert(res.responseText);
    },
    failure : function(res) {
        alert(res.responseText);
    }
}, formElements);
```

Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveData(ModelMap mm, @ModelAttribute("myPayload") MyBean bean,  BindingResult errors) {

    log.info("save:Called");
    List<MyDTO> lst = bean.getList();
    log.info("save:Number of records:" + lst.size());

    return "Successfully Updated.";
}
```

Bean Code:

```
public class MyBean {

    private List<MyDTO> myPayload = new  AutoPopulatingList<MyDTO>(MyDTO.class);

    public List<MyDTO> getList() {
        return myPayload;
    }

    public void setList(List<MyDTO> mList) {
        this.myPayload = mList;
    }

}
```

The list is still empty. The bean values are also empty. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you specify your command name as "myPayload" in your form?

Comment: Yes, in my formatter while creating elements I am giving the ids in that way. eg. id : "myPayload[" + index + "]." + oColumn.getKey(). I am getting the payload from the setForm API call in the JS file. I have mentioned that in my question. I am getting all the id:value map correctly in the JS before sending the request. But in the controller am not getting those. The payload is lost in the transit.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Does this work?

Adding `modelAttribute="contactForm"` in the form like

```
< form:form method="post" action="your url" modelAttribute="myPayload" >
```

Or use `@RequestBody`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveData(ModelMap mm, @RequestBody MyBean bean,  BindingResult errors) {
```

By the way, could yui (I'm not familiar with js) turn `myPayload[0].id=1&myPayload[0].name=Me&myPayload[0].pId=2&myPayload[0].pName=Dad` to JSON? It's not like common JSON after all.

**UPDATE**

**`@ModelAttribute` solution:
Change all `myPayload[x].foo=bar` as `list[x].foo=bar` (if list is the field name in MyBean) and keep `modelAttribute="myPayload"` in the form tag.**

`@RequestBody` solution:

Add jackson dependence if you use `@RequestBody`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 1. modelAttribute didn't work 2. @RequestBody is throwing some weird jackson baseclass not found exception.

Comment: @Sujoy does the "myPayload[0].id=1" string equals to < input name="myPayload[0].id" value="1"/> in YUI? I'm not familiar with this framework? and see the answer update for RequestBody issue.

Comment: Yes it's exactly the same. For RequestBody issue, that jackson jar is already there in the classpath, it's working for other controllers of the same project. Only for this controller it's not. It's very weird.

Comment: Could you post RequestBody error stack and check my ModelAttribute sulution update?

Comment: I am getting all my data in HttpRequest. "@RequestBody"
won't work because I am using a list and in Spring MVC it has no way to convert to an AutoPopulatingList other than "@ModelAttribute" with a bean having AutoPopulatingList.

Comment: Still could not fix this issue. It's very strange. Doesn't look like a rocket science, but not working.

Comment: @user:400545 Can you please answer? Could you please look into this? I am getting the values in HttpServletRequest and not getting any other errors?

Comment: @Sujoy Really sorry for this, but I have no further solution other than the bold @ ModelAttribute solution in my update. I still speculate the data you post does not match MyBean's structure.