# Get JSON from js/ajax in Controller Spring not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I know this may be asked before, but I have tried everything in stackoverflow and nothing has worked. I am using Spring Security so idk if this has anything to do. Having said that, the ajax POST request simply does not reach my controller, not even a error message or anything. The ajax POST request returns "sucess" but nothing happens.

I have tried
([Send json with Ajax to Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522326/send-json-with-ajax-to-spring-mvc))
([How to pass Json object from ajax to spring mvc controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245544/how-to-pass-json-object-from-ajax-to-spring-mvc-controller))
([Spring controller not getting JSON POST data from JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870313/spring-controller-not-getting-json-post-data-from-js-file))
and a few more.

JS

```
function cartData(){
    //var prods = [];
    //prods = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    var thing = {id: "1",cant:"1"};
    //console.log(prods);
    $.ajax({   
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'cart', 
        data: thing,
        success : function(result) {
             alert('success');
        },
         error : function() {
            alert("not working");
        }
});
}
```

Controller

```
//Class
public class Thing
    {
        private String id; 
        private String cant;
        
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getCant() {
            return cant;
        }
        public void setCant(String cant) {
            this.cant = cant;
        } 
        
    }
//Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/cart",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody String  cart(@RequestBody Thing thing, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Got Inside");

        return "public/carrito";
    }
```

Comment: did you try data: JSON.stringyfy(thing), ?

Comment: @PrakashS Yes, I tried it before and rigth now, but no changes. :(

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(thing),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',

Comment: @PrakashS if I set dataType: 'json' it return me an error (alert("not working");) which is weird. It's been 2 days with this error. So I kinda given up and I think I'll try something else.

Comment: check the network request and mostly it is a server parsing error. so the request is hitting the server/controller

Comment: @PrakashS I tried to post images of the network, but I dont have enough reputation lol. It seems to be a problem in spring security since it redirects me to the login page in the network redirects. Either way I'll check it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will increase it by up vote. Everyone deserves help